# $Z(GL_n(\mathbb R)) = \{aI : a\neq0\} $

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

$Z(GL_n(\mathbb R)) = \{aI : a\neq0\} $

[This article](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-gln-k) is the general case for $GL(n,k)$ where $k$ is a field. Could I prove it only with a basic linear algebra?

Comment: Well, the answer in that question is basic linear algebra.

Comment: @robjohn It even links to that question.

Comment: @ronno: then this is *not* a duplicate since it is asking for a simpler proof in a restricted case.

Comment: @robjohn Well up to people who can cast close votes. In my opinion, the existing answers there already answer this one as "simply" as it wants.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $A \in Z(GL_n(\mathbb R))$.

Let $B$ be defined as $b_{ii}=i$ and $b_{ij}=0$ if $i\neq j$ (or any other diagonal matrix with pairwise distinct entries).

Then since $AB=BA$, for all $i \neq j$ we have

$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_{ik}b_{kj}=\sum_{k=1}^n b_{ik}a_{kj} \Rightarrow a_{ij}b_{jj}=b_{ii}a_{ij}\,.$$

Since $i \neq j$ we have $b_{ii} \neq b_{jj} \Rightarrow a_{ij}=0$.

This proves that $A$ is a diagonal matrix.

Now, use the fact that $A$ commutes with permutation matrices. Let $\sigma=(i,j)$ be any transposition and $P_\sigma$ the corresponding matrix.

Then $AP_\sigma=P_\sigma A$ implies $a_{ii}=a_{jj}$.

**P.S.** If you work over a finite field with less elements that the size of the matrix, instead of a matrix $B$ in the first part you need to consider a family $B_{i,j}$ of diagonal matrices so that $b_{ii} \neq b_{jj}$. AND, you need to study separately the case $k=F_2$.

Answer (score 1):

We know that $G=GL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by elementary matrices. Therefore $A$ is in $Z(G)$ if and only it commutes with all elementary matrices. By checking this condition, you will see that $A$ has to be diagonal.

Comment: This is also in the linked question ...

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Maybe we don't have the same definition of elementary matrices. In any case, it wasn't stated explicitly.

Comment: You don't need that $G$ be generated by elementary matrices (not so easy). You simply need that it contain the transvections (trivial).

Comment: @julien I agree that you need less. But that $G$ is generated by elementary matrices is exactly that any invertible matrices can be brought to the identity matrix by elementary row (or column) operations, which is basic linear algebra.

Comment: I did not say it was hard, I am just saying that the fact the transvections are invertible is comnpletely trivial. Anyway, which elementary matrices will you use to deduce that $A$ is scalar? If not the transvections.

Comment: @julien All of them.