# Central idempotent vector space endomorphisms

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Let $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ be the endomorphism ring of the K-vector space V.
Are there any non-trivial central idempotent elements of $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$?
I already know that if $f\in \operatorname{End}_K(V)$ and $f$ is idempotent then $V=\operatorname{Ker}(f)\oplus \operatorname{Im}(f)$. Is this fact useful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The center of $\operatorname{End}_K(V)$ is the set of uniform scaling maps $\lambda \mathrm{Id}$. If such an element is also idempotent, you have $\lambda(\lambda-1)\mathrm{Id}=0$. Hence the identity and the zero linear map are the only possible central idempotent elements.

Comment: Explain to me why f is in the center implies that it is like you suggested.

Comment: You can have a look at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-operatornamegln-k which provides a proof oro the finite dimensional case that can be adapted to the general case.