# Ideals of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$

Tags: lie-groups, ideals, lie-algebras

How does one determine the ideals of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(C)$?

My guess is that the only ones are $(0) $ and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(C)$.

I think approaching the problem by the fact that each $\mathfrak{g}^{
(i)}$ is an ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ would be wise.

Answer (score 2):

Your guess is correct, with the exception that also the *center* is always a Lie ideal. Two days ago we have determined the center of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1641744/center-of-mathfrakgln-bbb-f-using-the-adjoint-representation), for a field $K$ of characteristic zero. Indeed, the center is $1$-dimensional, spanned by $I_n$. Since $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)\cong \mathfrak{sl}_n(K)\oplus K$, and $\mathfrak{sl}_n(K)$ is semisimple, the only ideals of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$  are
$$
(0), \; K, \, \mathfrak{sl}_n(K),\; \mathfrak{gl}_n(K).
$$

Answer (score 0):

$gl_n(C)$ is an example of reductive Lie algebra. You can write $gl_n(C)=sl_n(C)\oplus C$. Since $sl_n(C)$ is semi-simple. The only ideals of $gl_n(C)$ are $sl_n(C)$ and $C$.