# Finding center of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$ using elementary matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> I want center of $GL_n(\Bbb R)$.
>
> Artin, in his book Algebra, hints that, 'You are asked to determine the invertible matrices $A$ that commute with every invertible matrix $B$. Do not test with general matrix $B$, test with elementary matrices.'

I know that [Row-multiplying transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-multiplying_transformations) and [Row-addition transformations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Row-addition_transformations) generate $GL_n(\Bbb R).$ I also see that Row-multiplying transformations (unless all diagonal entries are 1's) and Row-addition transformations (unless all off-diagonal entries are 0's) don not commute with each other, so only elenentary matrix in center is $I$.

What I don't get is:

**1.** How do we derive from this that $cI$ is in center for any $c\in \Bbb R$? (I can see $cI$ in center, but, it did not click me, because I thought this way: since center is subgroup, $\langle I\rangle$ is in center, but $\langle I\rangle=\{I\}$. Where did I not think through?)

**2.** No other matrix is in center?

Comment: 1. We have $cI\cdot A=A\cdot cI$, so by definition $cI$ is in the center.

Comment: 2. Yes, no other matrix is in the center. For this we need the elementary matrices, see the duplicates. All of them do the same. See, for example, another duplicate [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-operatornamegln-k).

Comment: No, no, I know that why $cI$ is in center, i don't know how did we guess that in first place if all we knew was only elementary matrix in center is $I$. Also, what do you mean by duplicates? @DietrichBurde

Comment: The question you have has been answered several times. This is called a "duplicate". Did you see the answers? And why "No,no"? Of course we guess that the identity commutes with everything, hence also $cI$. We guess this, because we know that the identity commutes with all $A$, and not because of elementary matrices.

Comment: I am asking: only elementary matrix in center is $I$, right? *From that information,* how did we guess that $cI$ is in center? (I am sorry if I seem harsh, but believe me, i am a polite person, in fact i respect your decision to mark this as duplicate.) @DietrichBurde