# When The Center and Abelianization are Isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-groups, abelian-groups, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose that $G$ is a non-Abelian Lie group.  Is there a characterization of such groups $G$ for which 
$$
Z(G)\cong G/[G,G]?
$$

(Besides the case where $G$ is itself Abelian)?

Comment: What are some non-abelian examples of this?

Comment: I can't think of any non-trivial ones

Comment: Then I must ask:  why do you care?

Comment: To see if it Z(G) ever becomes functorial (when restricted)...out of curiosity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an important example. For any field $K$ of characteristic zero, the abelianization of $GL_n(K)$ is $K^{\times}$ since its commutator subgroup is $SL_n(K)$. Furthermore the center is given by $\lbrace\lambda I\mid \lambda \in K^{\times}\rbrace \cong K^{\times}$.

More generally, this holds for Lie groups of the form $S_1\times \cdots \times S_r\times T$ with semisimple $S_i$ and abelian $T$.

Comment: Huh, interesting..

Comment: I didn't know this, very interesting.  Would you happen to have a reference, I'd love to look at the proof :)

Comment: We have $GL_n(\Bbb C)=S\times \Bbb C^{\times}$ and $[S,S]=S$. The center is $\Bbb C^{\times}$. This is all for the proof. For the center see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/299626/the-center-of-operatornamegln-k).